# Mysql-how to update the "domain.com" in "address@domain.com"

Tags: mysql, email, email-address

In my database I have a lot of users who've misspelled their e-mail address. This in turn causes my postfix to bounce a lot of mails when sending the newsletter.
Forms include (but are not limited to) "yaho.com", "yahho .com" etc.
Very annoying!

So i have been trying to update those record to the correct value.
After executing `select email from users where email like '%@yaho%' and email not like '%yahoo%';` and getting the list, I'm stuck because I do not know how to update only the `yaho` part. I need the username to be left intact.

So I thought I would just dump the database and use vim to replace, but I cannot escape the `@` symbol..

BTW, how do I select all email addresses written in CAPS? `select upper(email) from users;` would just transform everything into CAPS, whereas I just needed to find out the already-written-in-CAPS mails.

Comment: If you require valid e-mail addresses, can you add an e-mail verification upon registration? You can't guarantee that changing bob@yaho.com to bob@yahoo.com will actually reach your registered user, nor that it will not also produce a bounce.

Comment: Indeed you're right, I also thought that any sane person should add validation. But I'm just the sysadmin over here and I thought to address the situation from my side. Will have to submit a bug or smth.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You may want to try something like the following:

```
UPDATE   users
SET      email = CONCAT(LEFT(email, INSTR(email, '@')), 'yahoo.com')
WHERE    email LIKE '%@yaho.com%';
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE users (email varchar(50));

INSERT INTO users VALUES ('test1@yahoo.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('test2@yaho.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('test3@yahoo.com');


UPDATE   users
SET      email = CONCAT(LEFT(email, INSTR(email, '@')), 'yahoo.com')
WHERE    email LIKE '%@yaho.com%';

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0


SELECT * FROM users;
+-----------------+
| email           |
+-----------------+
| test1@yahoo.com |
| test2@yahoo.com |
| test3@yahoo.com |
+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To answer your second question, you probably need to [use a case sensitive collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) such as the `latin1_general_cs`:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email COLLATE latin1_general_cs = UPPER(email);
```

Test case:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('TEST4@YAHOO.COM');


SELECT * FROM users;   
+-----------------+
| email           |
+-----------------+
| test1@yahoo.com |
| test2@yahoo.com |
| test3@yahoo.com |
| TEST4@YAHOO.COM |
+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT * FROM users WHERE email COLLATE latin1_general_cs = UPPER(email);
+-----------------+
| email           |
+-----------------+
| TEST4@YAHOO.COM |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Great example! Worked without problems. One thing though, the database is UTF8 so I cannot use latin1 collations. But not a big deal, the SELECT isn't vital, I just updated everything to lowercase.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm still coming back to this answer years later.

Comment: I am trying to put @ in a varchar. But is says extranoues... How to enter email adresses in mysql?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE users SET email = REPLACE( email, SUBSTRING_INDEX( email,  '@', -1 ) ,  CONCAT(user_id, 'domain.com' ) ) WHERE [MYSQL CONDITION];
```

To update live email address to test email address

Answer (score 2):

To address your second question (about finding emails written in caps), something like this might be helpful:

```
select email from users where upper(email) = email
```

(Forgive me if the syntax is not precisely correct, since I'm used to DB2. The idea is to compare the straight email address with the upper-cased version.)

Comment: @Syntactic: Note that the default character set and collation in MySQL are case insensitive by default. [Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo Good point. Learning something new every day.

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you mean. But instead of finding UPPER mails, it returns all lower cased mails.. about 50.000 of them :))
Fair enough with the case insensitive, there is no problem with sending mails or anything else, it's just that it bothered my eyes.

Comment: @w00t: If you want to convert all the emails to lowercase, you can simply do: `UPDATE users SET email = lower(email);`

Comment: @w00t: Do it on the application side, when inserting/updating the data, and you won't have to worry about it again.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE contacts SET email = REPLACE(email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1), 'domain.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `INSTR` together with `SUBSTR` or `LEFT` to get the part before the "@" symbol, perhaps.

Something like `SELECT LEFT("foo@yaho.com",INSTR("foo@yaho.com","@")-1);` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I would choose something like

```
UPDATE users
SET email = INSERT(email,INSTR(email,'@'), LENGTH(email), '@yahoo.com')
WHERE email LIKE '%@yaho.com'
```

Just for the sake of being thorough, this is multi-byte safe even though I've used `LENGTH`.  All that's needed is for the third argument of `INSERT` to be at least as large as the end of the substring.

Syntactic's answer of finding the all-caps email is a good answer.  Possibly performing slightly faster, although you would likely not notice the difference, is

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE BINARY(email) NOT REGEXP '[a-z]'
```

Update: `BINARY(email)` is needed to force case-sensitive matching.

Comment: I think you need to wrap the `@` in single quotes in the `INSTR()` function, otherwise it will return `NULL`. Also I guess your last query should look something like `FROM users WHERE email NOT REGEXP ...`.

Comment: Indeed, the `@` needed single quotes because it returned `NULL`. It worked after. The second query matches only emails that are made of numbers or +--_ but no alphabetical ones.